# Who teaches what classes after the Second Wizarding War?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

After WWII (Wizarding War II), who went to teach each one of the classes?

Minerva Mcgonagall became the Headmistress, and IIRC the DADA teacher is no longer present (having been replaced by Voldemort to Dark Magic classes) so who takes her and the other teachers' places when the whole ordeal is over?

Update: This asks about **all** of the teachers **including** DADA, and is more broad as a question than a single teacher. For instance Professor Trelawney is sacked by Umbridge, but does she resume upon the rehashing of the school staff?

Comment: I swear I had heard something about Ginny Weasley doing something or other at Hogwarts but I have no idea where the source would be if I'm right...

Comment: @Probst Ginny went to play Quidditch professionally, if I recall correctly. Neville became the Herbology professor, though.

Comment: I could be entirely wrong but I thought that she did that and then after she retired from that (Professional sports players never last that long lol) she started working at Hogwarts.

Comment: Ginny played Quidditch, retired to have a family with Harry and at some point become Daily Prophet Quidditch correspondent.

Comment: Very clearly not a dupe. Voted to reopen. No canon answer that I know of for know, though that may well change in a few months' time when _Curses Child_ opens—assuming Hogwarts is at least involved, there's likely to be some mention of which teachers teach what.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JK Rowling said in an interview with the Today Show that there was a permanent DADA teacher following the death of Voldement and that Harry gave occasional lectures, but nothing past that.

> Meredith Viera: Do Ron and Hermione or Harry ever return to Hogwarts in any capacity?
>
> JKR: Well, I can well imagine Harry returning to give the odd talk on-- on Defense Against the Dark Arts. And-- I-- and, of course, the jinx is broken now because Voldemort's gone. Now they can keep a good Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher from here on in. So that aspect of the-of the wizarding education is now provided for.

Since you ask about "other classes," we do know that Herbology was taken over by Neville Longbottom and that Hagrid is still living on the grounds, which means its likely he's still Care of Magical Creatures professor. But we know nothing about the other classes (although presumably Professor Binns will go on teaching forever).

Comment: Binns will still be going to class and teaching history to thin air long after Hogwarts itself has crumbled and turned to ruins.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess Flitwick continues to teach charms, as he does not die in the war.

Comment: Whilst guesses are answers we prefer answers to be backed in evidence on this site. Do you have any to [edit] in or is this just complete speculation?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot this is true, i can confirm from the book